# Send a line of text via http

Tags: excel, vba, post

I'm trying to build a simple macro, that just sends a line of data, preferably in JSON formatting, to an HTTP server.

The aim for this is that when the worksheet has been opened, with macros enabled, it'll fire off the signed in username, time & date, plus any other information I plan to add at a later date, to a HTTP server which should log the requests, which I can gather the information just fine, but when I try to post the information

However, the current state is giving me a run-time error.

```
UserName = Application.UserName

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Url = "http://192.168.0.17:8082"
objHTTP.Open "POST", Url, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"

JSONString = "{""Username"": UserName,""Date"":Date,""Time"":Time()}"

objHTTP.send JSONString
```

Tried to google the error, but either I'm not finding an answer or it's just not clicking with my brain.

[image]

Comment: I get that error if the URL is incorrect otherwise it works.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel silly...

After further investigation and thanks to the comment by CDP1802, the main issue, is that the server tool I was using wasn't handling multiple connections.

I used curl to test this process and while the first post was accepted, anything thereafter was ignored.

Lesson learned.